# Where to hide my firebase js script in a web project

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]Sometimes I inspect some webpages and I have found that most of the developers don't try to hide the API keys. While I don't want to show my js. Suggest where to deploy it.

I have tried to put it in a script and deploy in a different webpage and call it from there.

I want that my script will remain unchecked.
while it is difficult to put it somewhere where no one can find it.

Comment: Private keys should never be sent to the client to begin with. I think you're solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @DBS I have just posted the page source and you can see that in script tag my whole code is available.

Comment: You should always act like the reciever of your page understands every single line of code perfectly, because that way you know if sending a key to a user is a good idea (in most cases it's not).

Comment: This is by design -- you include the config in your webpage as-is.  You'll need to configure your security rules from within the Firebase console to prevent unwanted access.